# Tor installer download signature verification failure

Tags: verification

I have downloaded Tor installer and .asc file, and when attempting to [verify with Linux](https://www.torproject.org/docs/verifying-signatures.html.en) I run the command `gpg --verify tor-browser-linux32-6.5.1_en-US.tar.xz.asc tor-browser-linux32-6.5.1_en-US.tar.xz` after getting the fingerprint verified with no issue.

However, instead of signature verification, I get output:

```
xxx@xxx ~ $ gpg --verify tor-browser-linux64-6.5.1_en-US.tar.xz.asc
gpg: can't open `tor-browser-linux64-6.5.1_en-US.tar.xz.asc'
gpg: verify signatures failed: file open error
```

I've updated the command/file names for the 64 bit version I downloaded, I've got both files in the default downloads folder.

Can anyone shine some light here?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: first of all, you seem to be breaking the command up over two lines, it should be a single command like: `gpg --verify tor-browser-linux64-6.5.1_en-US.tar.xz.asc tor-browser-linux64-6.5.1_en-US.tar.xz`? secondly, the error suggests that you aren't able to open the file for reading, possibly a permissions error or the files are located in a different folder that the one you're currently in. What happens if you run `ls -al tor-browser-linux64-6.5.1_en-US.tar.xz.asc`?